# Change column name knockout simplegrid

Tags: knockout.js

I am able to bind data to knockout simple grid but is it possible to change the column names dynamically. The name of columns will be what user enters in text box. So this is my view model

```
var initialData = [{
name: "Well-Travelled Kitten",
sales: 352,
price: 75.95,
whatever: 10
 }, {
    name: "Speedy Coyote",
sales: 89,
price: 190.00,
whatever: 100
}, ];

function viewModel() {
var self = this;
self.queryResult = ko.observableArray();
this.update = function (data) {
    //this is an ajax call and return dateset back
    $.each(initialData, function (index, item) {
        self.queryResult.push(item);
    });


};

  self.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
   data: self.queryResult,
    columns: [
        { headerText: "Name", rowText: "name" },
        { headerText: "Sales ", rowText: "sales" },
        { headerText: "Price", rowText: function (item) { return "$" + item.price.toFixed(2) } }
    ],
    pageSize: 4
});


 }

var PagedGridModel = function (items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);

    this.jumpToFirstPage = function () {
     this.gridViewModel.currentPageIndex(0);
};
```

};

```
  ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FB6LA/35/)

Now just for demo is it possible to have column name as "Well-Travelled Kitten"
instead of currently hard coded column "Name" ?

In my real life scenario user will enter some text in textbox and that when we loads the grid then the column name will change to what is entered in textbox. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you can set the column name to be an observable from your view model.  The the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DoctorMick/FB6LA/37/.  The main changes are:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.NameTitle = ko.observable("Some title");
    self.queryResult = ko.observableArray();
    this.update = function (data) {
        self.NameTitle(initialData[0].name); 
        //YOUR EXISTING CODE...
    }

    self.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
       data: self.queryResult,
        columns: [
            { headerText: self.NameTitle, rowText: "name" },
            { headerText: "Sales ", rowText: "sales" },
            { headerText: "Price", rowText: function (item) { return "$" + item.price.toFixed(2) } }
        ],
        pageSize: 4
    });
}
```

Comment: Super. Somehow its not working in IE. In console i get message Access is denied  Widget.html line 1